# Custom adaptor for Listview gives an error

Tags: android, image, listview, textview

I would like to develop an activity which shows list of images with their name in listview format. i have code custom Adapter using BaseAdapter. while running in an Emulator always shows me an debugger window and nothing is apprearing on Emulator.

There are images (11) images in below specified folder and user permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is given.

Below is code. (ImageViewer.java)

```
package com.example.imageviewer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.audiofx.EnvironmentalReverb;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageViewer extends Activity {

    File oDirectory;
    ListView oLVImages ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_viewer);

        try
        {
            oLVImages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvImages);

            String strPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES;

            oDirectory = new File(strPath);
            Log.d("ImageViewer", strPath);


            populateImages (oDirectory);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("ImageViewer", "1 " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_image_viewer, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void populateImages (File oDirectory){
        try{
            File[] oFiles = oDirectory.listFiles();

            ArrayList<Image> oImages = new ArrayList<ImageViewer.Image>();

            for (int i = 0 ; i < oFiles.length;i++){
                if (oFiles[i].isFile())
                {
                    Image x = new Image();
                    x.imgPath = oFiles[i].getPath().toString();
                    x.imgName = oFiles[i].getName().toString();
                    oImages.add(x);
                }
            }

            ImageListAdapter oImageListAdapter = new ImageListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), oImages);

            oLVImages.setAdapter(oImageListAdapter);

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("ImageViewer", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    class Image{
        private String imgName ;
        private String imgPath;

        public Image(){
            super();
            imgName = "";
            imgPath = "";
        }

        public Image (String imgName, String imgPath){
            super();
            this.imgName = imgName;
            this.imgPath = imgPath;
        }

    }

    public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        ArrayList<Image> imgImageList;
        Context oContext;

        public ImageListAdapter(Context oContext, ArrayList<Image> oImage){
            this.imgImageList = oImage;
            this.oContext = oContext;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return imgImageList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.imgImageList.get(arg0);
        }

        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.getView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
            View oView = arg1;
            LayoutInflater inflater =  getLayoutInflater();
            oView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagedetail, null);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivimage);
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvimage);
            Image oIM = imgImageList.get(arg0);
            Bitmap oBM = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(oIM.imgPath);
            iv.setImageBitmap(oBM);
            tv.setText(oIM.imgName.toString());

            return oView;
        }

    }


}
```

strings.xml File:

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">ImageViewer</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_image_viewer">Image Viewer</string>

    <string name="ivimage"></string>
    <string name="tvheader">Photos</string>

</resources>
```

activity_image_viewer.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tvheader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/tvheader"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:background="#FF336699"
        />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lvImages"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

imagedetail.xml (layout file for each item of ListView)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:stretchColumns="1"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:id="@+id/tbllayout" >
      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tblrow"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ivimage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ivimage"
            />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/tvimage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Code working. Its great.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in custom Adapter

getview method

```
 public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.getView(arg0, arg1, arg2);
            View oView = arg1;
            LayoutInflater inflater =  getLayoutInflater();
            oView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagedetail, null);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)oView.findViewById(R.id.ivimage);
            TextView tv = (TextView)oView.findViewById(R.id.tvimage);
            Image oIM = imgImageList.get(arg0);
            Bitmap oBM = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(oIM.imgPath);
            iv.setImageBitmap(oBM);
            tv.setText(oIM.imgName.toString());

            return oView;
        }
```

layout inflate use widget,

> ImageView iv = (ImageView)oView.findViewById(R.id.ivimage);
>
> TextView tv = (TextView)oView.findViewById(R.id.tvimage);

Comment: i have used the same code in getView method of "ImageListAdapter" which extended BaseAdapter and still getting an error.

Comment: It is showing me "Confirm Perspective Switch" and while clicking on "Yes" then opens up debug mode and showing me "Thread[ <1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))

Comment: i have added trycatch blocks but it is not being caught in catch block and listview class is opened

Comment: showing me "Source not found" the Jar file "..." has no source attachment.